# Is there a method similar to buildArguments()?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

There used to be a method named [`buildArguments()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/8.2.0/firebase_database/Query/buildArguments.html) which was very useful for viewing query arguments. It seems that it was removed after the package version 9.0.0.

I was using it to print my queries to the console, so I was able to spot any mistakes. Was a new method introduced to replace `buildArguments()`?